# Regex won't check if there is space or not

Tags: java, regex, whitespace

I have this regex code:

```
match [a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\s?(\.|dot|\(dot\)|-|;|:|,)\s?(com|org|net|cz|co|uk|sk|biz|mobi|xxx|eu|me|io|lt)\b
```

And when someone advertises their own server like this:

```
m c . s e r v e r . c o m
```

it bypasses and send this message to server.

So, how to fix this? Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Please show us the code, and add a tag specifying the programming language you are using

Comment: What 's [a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+ sould match ?

Comment: This is Java language. Sorry, but I don't have source code. I'm using plugin.

[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+ would match text before .com (Or smth else) or after mc. (Or smth else)

Comment: Your `(com|org|net|...)` requires the presence of `com`, `org`, `net`, ... (without spaces) somewhere. The fact that `c o m` (with spaces) passes the test implies that something else is happening, but it's impossible to tell without knowing the context. What is the software your're using? What is the plugin for?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a workaround where you would use it to first format your text in a way that your regex would work. I may be miss some situations, if that is the case, just add a comment explaining and I will try to cover it.

Here is what I've made:

```
public static void findAd(String text){
    text = text.replaceAll("\\b(\\w) (?!\\w{2,})", "$1");
    text = text.replaceAll("(\\w+)(?:\\. )", "$1.");
    text = text.replaceAll("(\\w+)(?: dot )", "$1.");
    return text;
}
```

So, when you call this method like:

```
System.out.println( findAd("bla bla bla bla m c . s e r v e r . c o m bla bla bla") );
System.out.println( findAd("m c . s e r v e r . c o m bla bla bla") );
System.out.println( findAd("bla bla bla m c . s e r v e r . c o m") );
System.out.println( findAd("m c . s e r v e r . c o m") );
System.out.println( findAd("m c dot s e r v e r dot c o m") );
System.out.println( findAd("bla bla bla m c dot s e r v e r dot c o m bla") );
```

You will get as output:

```
bla bla bla bla mc.server.com bla bla bla
mc.server.com bla bla bla
bla bla bla mc.server.com
mc.server.com
mc.server.com
bla bla bla mc.server.com bla
```

Then just call your expression with your test like:

```
if (yourMethodThatCheckForAd(find(text))) ...
```

Or just add the code I provided into your existing method 
:)